# Django - struggling to submit input data to database

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I'm having some trouble sending data from a form to my database.

**The form:**

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="banner" style="border-top-left-radius: 5px; border-top-right-radius: 5px; border-bottom-left-radius: 5px; border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;">
      <h1 style="font-family: 'Baloo Chettan 2', cursive; font-size: 50px;">Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="colums" style="padding-left: 8px; padding-top: 20px;">
      <div class="item">
        <label for="i1"> Input One<span>*</span></label>
        <input id="i1" type="text" name="i1" placeholder="Data point 1" required/>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <label for="i2"> Input Two<span>*</span></label>
        <input id="i2" type="text" name="i2" placeholder="Data point 2" required/>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <label for="i3">Input Three<span>*</span></label>
        <input id="i3" type="text" name="i3" placeholder="Data point 3" required/>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <label for="i4">Input Four<span>*</span></label>
        <input id="i4" type="text" name="i4" placeholder="Data point 4" required/>
      </div>
    <div class="btn-block">
      <button type="submit" value="CalcData" style="width: 1052px; align-content: center; background-color: #3E828F;">Calculate</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**views.py:**

```
def save_data(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST.get('i1') and request.POST.get('i2') and request.POST.get('i3') and request.POST.get('i4'):
            data=CalcData()
            data.i1= request.POST.get('i1')
            data.i2= request.POST.get('i2')
            data.i3= request.POST.get('i3')
            data.i4= request.POST.get('i4')
            data.save()

            return render(request, 'home.html')  

    else:
        return render(request,'home.html')
```

**models.py:**

```
class CalcData(models.Model):
    i1 = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 100, decimal_places = 5)
    i2 = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 100, decimal_places = 5)
    i3 = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 100, decimal_places = 5)
    i4 = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 100, decimal_places = 5)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

This POST doesn't end up in my database, so I'm not sure where it's going. I would assume the problem is in my views code somewhere but I'm not sure where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the action in your form and add the url. like this:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'YOUR_APP_NAME: save_data' %}">
```

Answer (score 1):

The POST data is posted to the view handling the form page. If its not the view handling the form processing (which it seems), then you should make some changes to your form action attribute.

point it to the url that points to the save_data view function.